# Notepad++ deleting varying text after a common demoninator

Tags: notepad++

I recently exported a chatlog of mine which has come back with lots of additional info which I don't require.
I'm trying to purge all unnecessary data while also potentially reordering upwards of 1000's of lines.

What I'm currently looking at:

```
{"id":"123456789","username":"Yabeca","discriminator":"0","global_name":"Yabeca","content":"Hello","flags":0,"id":"987654321","timestamp":"2023-08-20T10:45:24.427000+00:00","tts":false,"type":0,"username":"Yabeca","date":"2023-08-20T10:45:24.427Z"}
```

What I want:

```
Username: "Yabeca", timestamp: "2023-08-20T10:45:24", content: "Hello"
```

How do I go about deleting things like dates where the date and time are different with every single message?
Can I reorder multiple lines to have the timestamp show before the content of a message?

I haven't tried a lot as I am fairly new to notepad++ and the whole editing thing but I played around with find and replace and managed to make the file more organized by adding \n where needed but I feel like I'm missing commands that allow me to filter stuff out I don't need.

Comment: Do you have access to something like Python or JavaScript?  It would be much easier to handle your requirement from a programming language which has JSON support.

Comment: I do not currently have access to either of those but if the tools I need to complete this are easily accessible I'd be willing to try my hand at anything new!
All I need a pointer in the right direction and some basic instructions with what functions and commands to mess around with

Answer (score 0):

If using another text editor - **EmEditor** , it's easy to extract wanted data from JSON in search & replace function by J mode. J mode means JavaScript syntax.

Find:**^.+$**

Replace:**\J a=JSON.parse('\0'); 'Username:' + a.username + ', timestamp: ' + a.timestamp + ', content: '+a.content**

Explanation of Replacement Expressions:

**\J**                  activate JavaScript mode.

**a=JSON.parse('\0')**  Parse JSON data as object.

**a.username, a.timestamp, a.content**.....can retrieve JSON values and then use "+" to connect them.

See the screenshot please.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution:

To achieve your goal in Notepad++, you can use regular expressions in the Find and Replace feature. Follow these steps:

1. Open your chatlog file in Notepad++.
2. Press `Ctrl + H` to open the Find and Replace dialog.
3. In the 'Find what' field, enter: `\{"id":"\d+","username":"([^"]+)","discriminator":"\d+","global_name":"[^"]+","content":"([^"]+)","flags":\d+,"id":"\d+","timestamp":"([^"]+)".+?\}`
4. In the 'Replace with' field, enter: `Username: "$1", timestamp: "$3", content: "$2"`
5. Check the 'Regular expression' option.
6. Click 'Replace All'.

This should transform the input format into the desired output format, extracting the username, timestamp, and content from each message. Make sure to backup your original file before performing the replace operation.

Comment: What would happen to your solution if the order of the `username`, `timestamp`, and `content` keys were different?

Comment: What happens if one of the values contains a `"`?

Comment: Here's an alternative regex that both takes into account the order and allows to have values with escaped commas (like `"Hel\"lo"`): find: `\{(?=.*"username":"((?:\\"|[^"])*))(?=.*"timestamp":"?(\d+-\d+-\d+T\d+:\d+:\d+))(?=.*"content":"((?:\\"|[^"])*))[^{}]*\}` replace with: `Username: "$1", timestamp: "$2", content: "$3"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lkVxju/1))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, justyce jaelen!

Your 7 answers so far appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). *Six* of those seven have comments from users indicating issues with the answer, which demonstrates why [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!